# Automatically convert comment to #pragma mark

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have long liked to visually segment Protocol implementation code using the following:

```
// UIApplicationDelegate ===========================================================================
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options {
```

However, the #pragma mark feature in Xcode is really quite useful.  I also like the ability to add dividing lines.  But this means my code now looks like:

```
// UIApplicationDelegate ===========================================================================
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options {
```

Which is becoming quite unwieldy.  I really like the nice (normally) green line marked with the protocol embedded into the code itself, but I also like the pragma mark utility.

Is there anyway using preprocessor `#define` or other such commands to automatically convert the first into the 2nd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang / Xcode also recognizes `// MARK:` for the same purpose as `#pragma mark`. (Also, this is the only style in Swift, since that language doesn't have a preprocessor.) So if you like green, you could do:

```
// MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
// ========================
```

If you're looking for a way to automatically convert all uses of your previous notation to `// MARK` or `#pragma`, I'd recommend a good regex find/replace utility, of which there are too many to list here.

Comment: The MARK: command gets me pretty much where I want to go.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a `#pragma` from a macro, but the text editor won't see it unless it does macro expansion.

The `_Pragma` "operator" is defined to have the same effect as a `#pragma` directive.

```
#define PRAGMA_STR( TEXT ) _Pragma( # TEXT )
#define INDEX_MARK( NAME ) _Pragma("mark -") PRAGMA_STR(mark NAME)
```

It won't work within a comment, but you could do something like

```
INDEX_MARK( UIApplicationDelegate ) // =======================================
```

… if the editor looked at macros, which it probably doesn't.

Comment: As written this doesn't really work.  I played around with the syntax, but couldn't fix it.  I do think this is close though.

Comment: @aepryus Sorry, I tried to be clear that it doesn't really work, because the text editor doesn't really do any preprocessing, but only uses a regex to find `#pragma` lines. In all likelihood, it also fails to handle quirks like `??=pragma`, `%:pragma`, line splices, etc.

Comment: Ya, I understood.  But it was sort of working, "NAME)" was getting placed in the drop down box.  So, I think it's close, but in the few minutes I played with it, I wasn't able to fix it.  At any rate, thanks for your help.

Comment: @aepryus Just a wild guess, but it probably indexed the `#define` line because it contains the `mark` identifier.